# Store uploaded image to AWS S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-views

I have a server application written in python/django (REST api) for accepting a file upload from the client application. I want this uploaded file to be stored in AWS S3. I also want the file to be uploaded from client as multipart form / data . How can i achieve this. Any sample code application will help me to understand the way it should be done. Please assist.

```
 class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        self.handle_uploaded_file(file_obj)
        return self.get_response("", True, "", {})

    def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
        destination = open('<path>', 'wb+')
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code to show us what is working or not working for you right now?

Comment: Write now, i am uploading the file to application root folder.. I want to change that and need to be uploaded to AWS s3

Comment: Please see the answer I posted below on using ``django-storages``.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to your uploads to go directly to AWS S3, you can use `django-storages` and set your Django file storage backend to use AWS S3.

- [django-storages](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages)
- [django-storages documentation](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

This will allow your Django project to handle storage transparently to S3 without your having to manually re-upload your uploaded files to S3.

**Storage Settings**

You will need to add at least these configurations to your Django settings:

```
# default remote file storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

# aws access keys
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY'
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = 'your-bucket-name'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = AWS_BUCKET_NAME
```

**Example Code to Store Upload to Remote Storage**

This is a modified version of your view with a the `handle_uploaded_file` method using Django's storage backend to save the uploade file to the remote destination (using django-storages).

Note: Be sure to define the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` and AWS keys in your `settings` so `django-storage` can access your bucket.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files import File

# set file i/o chunk size to maximize throughput
FILE_IO_CHUNK_SIZE = 128 * 2**10


class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        self.handle_uploaded_file(file_obj)
        return self.get_response("", True, "", {})

    def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
        """
        Write uploaded file to destination using default storage.
        """
        # set storage object to use Django's default storage
        storage = default_storage

        # set the relative path inside your bucket where you want the upload
        # to end up
        fkey = 'sub-path-in-your-bucket-to-store-the-file'

        # determine mime type -- you may want to parse the upload header
        # to find out the exact MIME type of the upload file.
        content_type = 'image/jpeg'

        # write file to remote server
        # * "file" is a File storage object that will use your
        # storage backend (in this case, remote storage to AWS S3)
        # * "media" is a File object created with your upload file
        file = storage.open(fkey, 'w')
        storage.headers.update({"Content-Type": content_type})
        f = open(path, 'rb')
        media = File(f)
        for chunk in media.chunks(chunk_size=FILE_IO_CHUNK_SIZE):
            file.write(chunk)
        file.close()
        media.close()
        f.close()
```

See more explanation and examples on how to access the remote storage here:

- [django-storages: Amazon S3](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)

Comment: I read the link, but i still has a question how can i make this uploaded to s3 from my "FileUploadView" class. How the method "handle_uploaded_file" can be changed?

Comment: Can you post the form you're using for the view and also the related model? If you are defining a field to use a ``FileField`` or ``ImageField`` the storage backend will automatically upload to your defined storage destination.

Comment: Additional note: But if the form in your view is not storing directly into your model (i.e. not a ModelForm), then you will have to manually store/upload the file using the storage backend. And you can do that in the processing code of your view after validating the form submission.

Comment: The FileUploadView api is written as REST, it's being called from a mobile device. so i am accessing the data posted as request.POST.get["<name>"] and like request.data['file'].

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that handles the upload?

Comment: I have added that above.

Comment: any luck on how to proceed?

Comment: Check the example code I just posted. You may need to adjust it to your configurations and test it out a bit. But this should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `boto` package which provides AWS APIs:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
s3 = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
b = s3.get_bucket('<bucket>')
mp = b.initiate_multipart_upload('<object>')
for i in range(1, <parts>+1):
    io = <receive-image-part>   # E.g. StringIO
    mp.upload_part_from_file(io, part_num=i)
mp.complete_upload()
```

Comment: Please explain what is <parts> in for i in range(1, <parts>): and for i in range(1, <parts>):

Comment: `<parts>` is the number of multipart uploads you are going to get... this is just an indication of what you can do, not final code...